# How to stop loop for a while in Python?

Tags: python, logging, with-statement, pynput, keylogger

I have this code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging
import time as t


def stop():
    print('Stop keylogging for a while')


def main():
    logging.basicConfig(filename=('keylog.txt'), level=logging.DEBUG, format=" %(asctime)s - %(message)s")

    def on_press(key):
        logging.info(str(key))

    with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener :
        listener.join()




main()
stop()
```

It writes your typed letters in a file, but I want to stop it for a while do another function and again start writing typed letters

So I just need to stop this function after 1 hour:

```
main()
```

Start this function:

```
stop()
```

And again start this function:

```
main()
```

And I want it to works in a loop

Easier:

```
def stop():
    print('Stop')


def main():
        while True:
            print("Working")     

while True:
# Again start main() function
        main()
# Do stop() function after 10 seconds
        stop()
```

When I start this code main() works infinitely, I want to stop it but after 10 seconds, and start stop() function, than again go to the main() function

Comment: you want it to pause for a period of time ?

Comment: maybe  => time.sleep("PUT TIME IN SECONDS")

Comment: I want to pause main() start stop() than again continue main()

Comment: main() works in a loop

Comment: so then you can just call the function in that particular order ... that should do it no ?

Comment: The keylogger gets stuck in a loop, and doesn't execute the code after

Comment: I am unable to clearly understand what is going on. I apologize I am unable to assist you further

Comment: def stop():
 print('Stop')


def main():
        while True:
            print("Working")     

while True:
        main()

        stop()

When I start this code main works infinitely, I want to stop it, but after 10 seconds and start stop() function, again go to the main() function

Answer (score 0):

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def main():

    print('Working')

def stop():
    print('stopped')

while 1:
    t = Thread(target=main)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(6)
    t.join()
    stop()
```

you can use thread for it

Comment: I wrote easier explanation plz read

Comment: maybe you can use a callback on while loop ang give sleep time to time.sleep() function